# Text Editor Example for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, text, editor

My program requires TXT/RTF editor functionality. I've only been able to find an old Apple example at [Database Example: A Simple Text Editor](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/ASimpleExample/ASimpleExample.html). Unfortunately, its a Javascript program.

I've also seen a few text editor questions on stackoverflow. However, they seem to be mostly related to design and architecture.

My question is, are there any modern examples of an iOS/Objective C text editor from Apple to use as a starting point?

Comment: the question in SO should be about the programming, and not about the text editors ;)

Comment: @Serge- Indeed, it is off-topic. Please vote to close. I've tried deleting it several times in the past, but I am not allowed to do so.

Comment: there is any sense to downvote it, but as you did to my question and you have more experience, I will down-vote it, even closed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UITextView for text editing. If you need rich text, you have to write something on your own - not currently available. Cocoanetics did start implementing rich text label at https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML and AFAIK he did want to create rich text editor too (at least I read this on Twitter).