# Is there a open source rich text editor for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, open-source, text, editor

I am looking for an open source **rich text editor**, that I can integrate with my project on the **iPad** ,, so is such a thing available ??

Thanx

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351995/iphone-text-editor-example/5352093#5352093 Try to use search text field before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could also use `UIWebView` as well,if you do'nt support editing of text (for readonly purpose).

Comment: Yes I want to support text editing as well, do you know a thing for that ? Thanx

Comment: @Chiefly Izzy :than suggest you to go with Chiefly Izzy 's link  and also check whether this provide editing support or not ....

Comment: @Khaled Amr Shokry: Accept my answer if it help you ..

Comment: I cant run the Text Editor example, I downloaded the file project then tried to build it in Xcode, but i get header not found errors

Comment: @Khaled Amr Shokry: Could you post your error msg .. ?

Answer (score 2):

**Omni Group Text Editor** is very useful, it supports rich text viewing and editing, but unfortunately it does not support adding links and bullet points.

Answer (score 0):

Basic rich text editing works quite well using UITextView on iOS 6 or higher. You can use my DTCoreText library to convert between HTML and NSAttributedString: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText

If you need more features (like embedded images or iOS 5 support) I have a commercial component available for licensing: http://www.cocoanetics.com/parts/dtrichtexteditor/